# Cannot Kill process in manjaro using kill -l

Tags: archlinux

I have tried to get the kill table in arch linux normally kill -l worked in Debian based linux but not working in manjaro can some one help ?

Comment: Needs to be edited

Answer (score 0):

Is the package [psmisc](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/psmisc/) installed? This package contains the `kill` command. To install the package run in the terminal `sudo pacman -S psmisc` 
The `xkill` command only works on Xorg. If you are using Wayland this command will not work. To work on Xorg the xorg-xkill package must be installed with `sudo pacman -S xorg-xkill`.
In Wayland you can use the [`kill`](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/kill.1.html) command. To check the process PID you can use the `ps aux` command.
Example:

```
ps aux | grep program_name
kill -9 process_number

ps aux | grep nautilus
kill -9 25704
```

I apologize if I didn't understand your question.